# MySQL complex select query filtering from third table

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have three tables.

`users, friends and communityusers` tables.

I am trying to build a facebook like group system. User will try to search his/her friends from friend lists to add them to the group.

So here I am trying to remove those friends who are already added in the group. Here group users table is `communityusers`..

This is the structure of my `communityusers` table.

```
id | community_id | user_id
```

I am not being able to use this table with my current query.

```
SELECT f.id, u.id as user_id, u.userName, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.profilePic from friends f, users u

WHERE CASE 
WHEN f.following_id=1
THEN f.follower_id = u.id 
WHEN f.follower_id=1
THEN f.following_id = u.id
END 
AND
f.status= 2
AND 
  (
     u.firstName LIKE 's%' OR u.lastName LIKE 's%'
  )
```

This query returns the friends lists of user id `1` now I want exclude users filtering from the `communityusers` table. 
`user_id` from this query shouldn't be present in the `communityusers` table. How can I filter this from `communityusers` or third table?

Please let me know if question is not clear.

Any suggestion, idea and help would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you so much.

**Edit**

After running the query I get 
[image]

My `communityusers` table

[image]

See `user_id = 2` is also selected from the above query. I want to remove the `user_id = 2` from the result since it exists in the `communityusers` table.

I am trying to create a Fiddle but for some reason it's not working for me.

Thank you again.

Comment: can you please provide some sample data with your question

Comment: Sure. attaching some data in my question..

Comment: *So here I am trying to remove those friends who are already added in the group.* Why? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sadek
Simply use not in, in where condition

```
SELECT f.id, u.id as user_id, u.userName, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.profilePic
from friends f inner join users u on
CASE WHEN f.following_id=1 THEN f.follower_id = u.id WHEN f.follower_id=1 THEN f.following_id = u.id
END AND f.status= 2
where u.id not in (select distinct user_id from communityusers) and (u.firstName LIKE 's%' OR u.lastName LIKE 's%')
```

Comment: @sadek to check perticular community group you can use like this

SELECT f.id, u.id as user_id, u.userName, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.profilePic from friends f inner join users u
on CASE WHEN f.following_id=1 THEN f.follower_id = u.id WHEN f.follower_id=1 THEN f.following_id = u.id
END AND f.status= 2 where u.id not in (select user_id from communityusers where community_id=4) and (u.firstName LIKE 's%' OR u.lastName LIKE 's%')

Comment: Simply awesome answer. It works nicely also with my extra condition.

Comment: @sadek I'm happy that it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using left join with communityuser table by given condition cu.user_id is null - this will give you those users which are not in communituuser table

```
select a.* from 
(SELECT f.id, u.id as user_id, u.userName, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.profilePic from friends f inner join users u
on CASE WHEN f.following_id=1 THEN f.follower_id = u.id WHEN f.follower_id=1 THEN f.following_id = u.id
END AND f.status= 2 where u.firstName LIKE 's%' OR u.lastName LIKE 's%')a
left join (select * from communityuser where community_id<>4) cu on a.user_id=cu.user_id
where cu.user_id is null
```

Comment: Works great. One more help. I tried to add another `AND` like this 
`where cu.user_id is null and cu.community_id=4` to search in the right `group/community`.. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: put this condition in on clause like user_id=cu.user_id and cu.community_id=4

Comment: Doesn't work. Could you please update it in your answer please?

Comment: can you please this scenario first what exactly you want - you want those user who are not in community_id 4

Comment: Thank you for the help. I get `Unknown column 'cu.community_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Thank you boss for the help. I think @adaptable.services answer works perfectly and also he seems to be new so checking his answer as correct, please don't mind :) your one also will work..

Comment: @sadek, no issues bro :) glad that you got your desired answer